# Trying to grab a prop value of a list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to grab the value of amount prop and the years prop, but getting undefined using the below code. I have included the list item image from which I want to grab the prop values

```
let temp1;
if(amount !== null){
  temp1 = amount.map((amount,i) => {
    return(
      <li onClick={getValue.bind(this)} key={i} amount={amount.amount} years={amount.years}> 
        Amount: {amount.amount} Years: {amount.years} 
      </li>
    )
  })
}

function getValue(e){
  console.log(e.target.amount);   //change needed
  console.log(e.target.years);   //change needed
}
```

Comment: Please post more code like the props you are getting, the map function with which you are iterating among others.

Comment: i added the code for the map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getAttribute` method.

```js
const amounts = [{ amount: 11, years: 10 }];

const App = () => {
  return amounts.map(({ amount, years }, i) => {
    return (
      <li onClick={getValue} key={i} amount={amount} years={years}>
        Amount: {amount} Years: {years}
      </li>
    );
  });
};

function getValue(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('amount')); //change needed
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('years')); //change needed[enter image description here][1]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

However, it's not a good way to do so. It'll be better to bind values to on click like:

```js
const amounts = [{ amount: 11, years: 10 }];

const App = () => {
  return amounts.map(({ amount, years }, i) => {
    return (
      <li key={i} onClick={() => getValue({ amount, years })}>
        Amount: {amount} Years: {years}
      </li>
    );
  });
};

function getValue({ amount, years }) {
  console.log(amount); //change needed
  console.log(years); //change needed[enter image description here][1]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your click listener to

```
<li onClick={() => getValue.bind(this, amount)} key={i} />




function getValue(amount){
  console.log(amount.amount);
  console.log(amount.years);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the `e` argument in your getValue function is a normal DOM event object and doesn't know anything about React. It does know about your rendered HTML element attributes, but `amount` and `years` are not valid HTML attributes. One way around this is to use plain HTML data attributes, like this:

```
let temp1;
if (amount !== null) {
    temp1 = amount.map((amount, i) => {
        return (
            <li onClick={getValue.bind(this)} key={i} 
                data-amount={amount.amount} 
                data-years={amount.years}> 
                Amount: {amount.amount} Years: {amount.years} </li>
        )
    })

}


function getValue(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.amount);
    console.log(e.target.dataset.years);
}
```

For more info about data-* attributes, cf. [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs_universels/data-*)